# How to convert between Terraform Framework Plugin complex types and Golang types?

Tags: go, terraform

In the official Terraform Framework plugin examples, there are currently only very simple examples of CRUD'ing resources involving simple types.

If we use a complex type like a map, the code becomes extremely verbose. This is what I am doing currently but it feels wrong.

If I have a resource `foo`, with a map attribute `bar`:

```golang
func (r *FooResource) Read(ctx context.Context, req resource.ReadRequest, resp *resource.ReadResponse) {
    var data *ResourceModel

    // Read Terraform prior state data into the model
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(req.State.Get(ctx, &data)...)

    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    // call API to get "real" state

    foo, err := r.GetFoo(data.Id.ValueString())
    if err != nil {
        resp.Diagnostics.AddError(
            "Error reading foo",
            fmt.Sprintf("Error reading foo: %s", err),
        )
        return
    }

    // check to see if real data.Bar is actually different from foo.Bar, if so update

    newBar, barDiag := checkIfMapHasChanged(ctx, data.Bar, foo.Bar)
    if barDiag != nil {
        resp.Diagnostics.Append(barDiag...)
        return
    }
    data.Bar = newBar

    // Save updated data into Terraform state
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(resp.State.Set(ctx, &data)...)
}

// helper functions

func goMapFromTf(ctx context.Context, m types.Map) (map[string]interface{}, diag.Diagnostics) {
    goObject := make(map[string]interface{})
    // read from the terraform data into the map
    if diags := m.ElementsAs(ctx, &goObject, false); diags != nil {
        return nil, diags
    }
    return goObject, nil
}

func tfMapFromGo(ctx context.Context, m map[string]interface{}) (types.Map, diag.Diagnostics) {
    mappedValue, diags := types.MapValueFrom(ctx, types.StringType, m)
    if diags != nil {
        return types.MapNull(nil), diags
    }
    return mappedValue, nil
}

func checkIfMapHasChanged(ctx context.Context, tfMap types.Map, comparisonMap map[string]interface{}) (types.Map, diag.Diagnostics) {

    goTfMap, diags := goMapFromTf(ctx, tfMap)
    if diags != nil {
        return types.MapNull(nil), diags
    }

    // compare the map to the response from the API and if it's changed update the data object
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(goTfMap, comparisonMap) {
        tfFromComparison, err := tfMapFromGo(ctx, comparisonMap)
        if err != nil {
            return types.MapNull(nil), err
        }
        return tfFromComparison, nil
    }

    return tfMap, nil
}
```

I am checking if the value has actually changed as if I don't, the Terraform plan will show a diff, with no actual changes to be made.

This also makes some assumptions about the type contained in the map which I think I could solve for with generics.

I also need to write a similar helper function for lists and other complex types.

Comment: If I'm reading https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/types-list-usage/63422/2 correctly, yes that's the way to go. Have you raised an issue in the framework repo to improve upon that?